# performance of PivotTable from C# Deedle library

Tags: c#, dataframe, pivot-table, deedle

I am trying PivotTable from Deedle libaray on a dataframe. Here's the simple c# code snippet to demonstrate the issue:

```
DateTime sdt = new DateTime(2015,7,1);
DateTime edt = new DateTime(2015,7,10);
string query = string.Format("select dt, ticker, price from data_table where dt>='{0}' and dt<='{1}'", sdt, edt);

using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(dbcon))            
{
    sqlcon.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon))
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        Frame<int, string> dfRaw = Frame.ReadReader(reader);

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();                    
        Frame<string, string> df = dfRaw.PivotTable<int, string, string, string, decimal>("dt", "ticker", a => Decimal.Parse(a.GetColumn<string>("price").Values.First()));                    
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

I am trying to build dataframe of 10-by-8000 (10 days worth price data for 8000 tickers) by calling PivotTable. This pivotting operation, however, takes longer than 400k ms and I must be missing something. Can you please help me with the optimal usage of PivotTable from Deedle and what sort of performance I should be expecting, given the dimension of dataframe is likely to be much larger in real life cases? Thank you.

Comment: I'd like to run some tests - how many data do you have for one day? (Then the total number of rows will be `rowsPerDay*8000*10` in this example, right?)

Comment: @Tomas, there's only one price per ticker per day. The total number of rows in `reader` in the example is 8000*10.